# Accessing Ubuntu terminal of a system outside LAN, but connected to internet

Tags: command-line, ssh, putty

I know how to access remote terminal of an Ubuntu machine from a Windows machine using PuTTY when both the machines are part of same LAN.

Is it possible to use the same method for two machines connected over the Internet?

I searched the Internet for an answer, but had less luck finding what I need. 
It will be useful if someone could answer or point-out a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set port-forwarding on the router that connects you to the internet.

for example (choose a port number yourself):
port 10022 on the router, forwarded to port 22 of your ubuntu ip.
(I would use a port > 10000 because some providers block standard ports, and 10022 reminds me it's ssh.)

Then find out your 'internet ip', with  http://whatismyip.com

From somewhere else on the internet, then you can putty or ssh to that 'internet ip' on port 10022. What will be forwarded by your router to port 22 of your ubuntu ip.

So you will need to figure out how to configure that on your router. And have a good password, or not always leave that open ... for security reasons.

(Here port 22 is used to forward directly, what might not work or isn't advised to do so)
[image]

Comment: This helped.Thanks. I hope apart from router settings, other things remains the same as that of connecting machines inside the same LAN.

Comment: Depending on how complicated the network/LAN is. On a simple home network, ... this should be sufficient.